# Animated sprite without spritesheet

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to create an animated sprite in cocos2d-js, but I don't want to use a spritesheet as I did in my cocos2d-iphone project:

```
NSMutableArray *animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    int frameCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
    CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero-%d.png",i]];
    [animationFrames addObject:spriteFrame];
    }
NSLog(@"cria sprite com frames");
_player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:animationFrames.firstObject];
```

How can I do this in cocos2d-js? I didn't find the same functions in cocos2d-js documentation.

Comment: animations and sprite sheets are two separate concepts, you can use them together but it is not required to do so. Are you asking how to play sprite animations in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe following code is a little more complicated as it could be. But it works and loads sprites from files and puts together an animation and uses it in a runAction on a sprite (animFrame is an empty array, "this" is a ccLayer).

```
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    str = "mosquito_fly" + (i < 10 ? ("0" + i) : i) + ".png";
    var texture = cc.textureCache.addImage("res/Murbiks/"+str);
    var spriteFrame = cc.SpriteFrame.create(texture,cc.rect(0,0,96,96));
    animFrames.push(spriteFrame);
}

var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.06+Math.random()*0.01, 10);
var animate = this.animateMostafa = cc.Animate.create(animation);

// Create sprite and set attributes
mostafa = cc.Sprite.create(res.Mostafa_single_png);        
mostafa.attr({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scale: 0.60+Math.random()*0.3,
    rotation: 0
});
this.addChild(mostafa, 0);
```